# Magento 2 catalog_product_get_final_price event not working

Tags: magento2, product, event-observer, price

I have to set the product price to a custom value depends upon the customer. So I have written an event catalog_product_get_final_price and in the observer, I have set the custom price for the product.

below is my event xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Pawan_Catalog Module 
 *
 * @category    Catalog
 * @package     Pawan_Catalog
 * @author      pawan
 *
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_get_final_price">
        <observer name="setfinalprice" instance="Pawan\Catalog\Observer\FinalPricemanipulation" />
    </event>


</config>
```

My observer file is

```
<?php

/**
 * Pawan_Catalog Module 
 *
 * @category    checkout
 * @package     Pawan_Catalog
 * @author      pawan
 *
 */

namespace Pawan\Catalog\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class FinalPricemanipulation implements ObserverInterface {

    protected $scopeConfig;
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig, \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/observerslogs.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $pId = $product->getId();
        $qty = $observer->getEvent()->getQty();
        $actionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
                $logger->info($actionName);
        if (empty($qty) || ($qty == 1)) {

            $productQuantity = $objectManager->get('Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface')->getStockItem($pId);
//          $logger->info($product->getMeasurementSoldInSize() . "===" . $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty());
            if ($product->getMeasurementSoldInSize() > $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty()) {
                $finalPrice = $product->getData("final_price");
                $finalPrice *= $product->getMeasurementSoldInSize();
                $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
            } elseif ($productQuantity->getMinSaleQty() > 1) {
                $actionName = $this->request->getFullActionName();
                $logger->info($actionName);
                if ($actionName == 'catalog-product-view') {
                    $finalPrice = $product->getData("final_price");
                    $finalPrice *= $productQuantity->getMinSaleQty();
                    $product->setFinalPrice($finalPrice);
                }
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
```

but is not for view page it working when i add product to cart can any one tell why if anything i did wrong

Comment: is the  Pawan\Catalog\Observer\FinalPricemanipulation  class  hit? ensure that the observer clas hit?

Comment: yes,it was excuting in while adding to cart what i am looking is when i open product i need to set final price

Answer (score 0):

If it will work then there might be some other module that have overridden final price using plugin

if it won't work on default magento then there  are some issues in your observer code.

Observers  like:-

```
<?php

namespace [Vendorname]\[Modulename]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;

class FinalPricemanipulation implements ObserverInterface
{
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        //logic
    }
}
```

Comment: one of extension using below code can pls check

Comment: namespace MageWorx\OptionFeatures\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use MageWorx\OptionFeatures\Helper\Data as Helper;

class AroundGetBasePrice  
public function aroundGetFinalPrice($subject, $proceed, $qty, $product)
    {
   
        $this->eventManager->dispatch('catalog_product_get_final_price', ['product' => $product, 'qty' => $qty]);
        $basePrice = min($product->getData('final_price'), $subject->getBasePrice($product, $qty));

Comment: is this problem

Comment: yes @ pawankumar

Comment: how can i implement for both need to work like any doc

Answer (score 0):

Use `catalog_product_load_after` event instead of `catalog_product_get_final_price` for magento v2.4